# TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable

Tags: arrays, numpy, callable

I have seen other people asking something similar but I can not figure out the problem anyway.
I am trying to translate a Matlab code to Python and I have a problem after the following line in the FOR loop:

dx = abs(np.diff(g_coord(num)))

Below you have the code up to that loop. Any help will be appreciated. I really tried to fix it by myself but unsuccessfully. Sorry if it is a stupid mistake. The MATLAB lines are kept as Python comments in case it helps.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import lil_matrix 

# physical parameters
seconds_per_yr = 60*60*24*365; # number of seconds in one year
lx = 10000 ; #length of spatial domain (m)
Cp = 1e3 ; # rock heat capacity (J/kg/K)
rho = 2700 ; # rock density (kg/mˆ3)
K = 3.3 ; # bulk thermal conductivity (W/m/K)
kappa = K/(Cp*rho); # thermal diffusivity (mˆ2/s)
Tb = 0 ; # temperatures at boundaries (o C)
A = 2.6e-6 ; # heat production (W/mˆ3)
H = A/(rho*Cp); # heat source term (o K/s) % numerical parameters
dt = 1000*seconds_per_yr ; # time step (s)
ntime = 5000 ; # number of time steps
nels = 40 ; # total number of elements
nod = 2 ; # number of nodes per element
nn = nels+1 # total number of nodes
dx = lx/nels ; # element size

g_coord =  np.arange(0, lx+1, dx)#[0:dx:lx] 
bcdof = np.array([1, nn]); #[ 1 nn ] ; boundary nodes
bcval = np.array([Tb, Tb]); #[ Tb Tb ] ; # boudary values

g_num = np.zeros((nod, nels), float); #zeros(nod,nels) ;
g_num[0,:]=np.arange(1, nn); #g_num(1,:) = [1:nn-1] ;
g_num[1,:]=np.arange(2, nn+1); #g_num(2,:) = [2:nn] ;


# initialise matrices and vectors
ff = np.zeros((nn,1), float); # system load vector
b = np.zeros((nn,1), float); # system rhs vector
lhs=lil_matrix((nn, nn)) #lhs = sparse(nn,nn); system lhs matrix
rhs=lil_matrix((nn, nn)) #rhs = sparse(nn,nn); system rhs matrix
displ = np.zeros((nn,1), float); # initial temperature (o C)


#-----------------------------------------------------
# matrix assembly
#-----------------------------------------------------

# Matlab version of the loop
#-----------------------------------------------------
#for iel=1:nels # loop over all elements
#    num = g_num(:,iel) ; # retrieve equation number
#    dx = abs(diff(g_coord(num))) ; # length of element
#    MM = dx*[1/3 1/6 ; 1/6 1/3 ] ;# mass matrix
#    KM = [kappa/dx -kappa/dx ; -kappa/dx kappa/dx ]; #diffn matrix
#    F = dx*H*[1/2 ; 1/2] ; # load vector
#    lhs(num,num) = lhs(num,num) + MM/dt + KM ; # assemble lhs
#    rhs(num,num) = rhs(num,num) + MM/dt ; # assemble rhs
#    ff(num) = ff(num) + F ; # assemble load
#end # end of element loop

#Python version of the loop
#-----------------------------------------------------
for iel in range(0, nels): # loop over all elements
    num = g_num[:,iel]  # retrieve equation number
    #print(num)
    dx = abs(np.diff(g_coord[num]))  # length of element
    MM = dx*(np.array([[1/3, 1/6],[1/6, 1/3]]))  # mass matrix
    KM = np.array([[kappa/dx, -kappa/dx],[-kappa/dx, kappa/dx]]) 
    F = dx*H*(np.array([1/2, 1/2])).reshape(-1,1) # load vector
    lhs[num,num] = lhs[num,num] + MM/dt + KM # assemble lhs
    rhs[num,num] = rhs[num,num] + MM/dt # assemble rhs
    ff[num] = ff[num] + F # assemble load
```

Comment: If I modify that line for this "dx = abs(np.diff(g_coord[num]))"  using square brackets this other error message appears:  "arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type"

Comment: Please clarify.  The `callable` error occurred when you tried to index an array with `()` (matlab style), right?  You correct that, and you get this `integer` error?  New versions of `numpy` have gotten picky about the index type.  Why did you intialize `g_num` as `float`?

Comment: Regarding the `lil` sparse matrix - this is a start.  But collecting element values in `coo` style inputs is probably faster.  At least that's how I used to do with in MATLAB.  Duplicates in `coo` inputs are summed when converted to `csr` for calculation purposes.

Comment: Matlab use () for both function arguments and indexing.  Python uses [] for indexing.

Comment: yes, you are right, maybe I made a mistake initializing g_num as float as well. I used lil sparse matrix bc it looked similar to the sparse() common in Matlab, but I did not exactly knew the differences with coo style. Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: I was thinking of the `sparse(i,j,v)` method of creating a matrix.  `sparse.coo_matrix((v, (i.j)))` is similar.  Matlab saves sparse matrices to .mat` files in `csc` compatible format (via scipy.io.loadmat).

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be because `num` is a `float`.
Simply do:

`dx = abs(np.diff(g_coord[np.int32(num)]))`

However it raises another error a few lines later because `num` is a 2-element array. You know what the code should do which I do not. If you have more issues, you can comment below or edit your question with the first problem solved.

Also, I noticed that you left all the `;` at the end of the lines as in Matlab. You do not need this in Python. Also, I think there is no need for you to specify `float` when you create the matrices of `zeros`, they naturally are `float`.

Comment: thank you very much, I really appreciate you took the time to look at it, best regards.